# Trying to match on a c-style array in gmock is failing at compile time

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

**Background:**

I'm mocking a hardware i2c transmit function, and trying to match on an array passed into it. This is in an embedded context, hence the c-style arrays and lack of STL containers.

Trying to match my second parameter, a c-style array (the buffer below), is failing at compile time.

**Setup:**

The interface defined as:

```
virtual I2C_Status_e i2c1Transmit(uint8_t address, 
                                  const uint8_t buffer[], 
                                  uint8_t length) = 0;
```

And I'm setting up my test mock as:

```
MOCK_METHOD(I2C_Status_e,
            i2c1Transmit,
            (uint8_t address, const uint8_t buffer[], uint8_t length),
            (override));
```

Call point in the binary (this transmit sends a single 8-bit command):

```
status = hal->i2c1Transmit(address, readStatusCommand, 1);
```

Where readStatusCommand is def as:

```
const uint8_t readStatusCommand[1] = {0x00};
```

**Test Code:**

Here readStatusCommand has an identical signature to the one above.

```
EXPECT_CALL(hal, i2c1Transmit(address0, ElementsAreArray(readStatusCommand, 1), txLength))
    .WillOnce(Return(HAL_Ok));
```

**Compiler Output:**

```
/home/.../vendor/gtest/googletest-release-1.10.x/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In instantiation of ‘class testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcherImpl<const unsigned char* const&>’:
/home/.../vendor/gtest/googletest-release-1.10.x/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3518:31:   required from ‘testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<T>::operator testing::Matcher<T>() const [with Container = const unsigned char*; T = unsigned char]’
/home/.../..._tests.cpp:88:5:   required from here 
    ^^^* Note: Expect Call above is line 88 here. *^^^
/home/.../vendor/gtest/googletest-release-1.10.x/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3084:45: error: ‘testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcherImpl<const unsigned char* const&>::StlContainer’ {aka ‘const unsigned char*’} is not a class, struct, or union type
 3084 |   typedef typename StlContainer::value_type Element;
      |                                             ^~~~~~~
/home/.../vendor/gtest/googletest-release-1.10.x/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:3218:43: error: ‘testing::internal::StlContainerView<const unsigned char*>::type’ {aka ‘const unsigned char*’} is not a class, struct, or union type
 3218 |   ::std::vector<Matcher<const Element&> > matchers_;
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
```

**Expected behavior/What I tried:**

According to [the matcher documentation here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md), it should work? ElementsAreArray is defined as working on c-style arrays if a length is passed in. I tried ElementsAre to the same effect.

It's also definitely the matcher, switching the matcher for ::_ allows it to compile fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it should not work - [the matcher documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md) refers to the case where the argument being matched is an STL container, whereas `const uint8_t buffer[]` is a pointer.

The `ElementsAreArray(readStatusCommand, 1)` is a matcher for a container of length 1. However the second argument that it is being compared with doesn't have an associated length.

This will work, see *ii.* in *These matchers can also match* notes, that refers to [Multi-argument Matchers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md#multi-argument-matchers-multiargmatchers).

```
EXPECT_CALL(hal, i2c1Transmit(address0, _, _))
    .With(Args<1, 2>(ElementsAreArray(readStatusCommand)))
    .WillOnce(Return(HAL_Ok));
```

`ElementsAreArray(readStatusCommand)` does not require setting the explicit array length, since `readStatusCommand` has type `const uint8_t[1]` that has an associated length.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I missed the fact that it needed to be an STL container, and the template errors threw me off. This (and the linked documentation) is fantastic.